# Loading GeoTiff with specified color band from ArcGIS to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, raster, style

I have just started experimenting with QGIS. I have a GeoTIFF that I loaded in QGIS and used Singleband psuedocolor to create nice color codings for the map. However, my employer has specific colorband stored in his computer that he wants me to use. I don't know how can I export his specific colorband from ArcGIS and use it in my QGIS.

So far, I tried using the .clr file, but it didn't help me out.

Comment: What happened when you tried his .clr file?

Comment: The QGIS does not accept .clr file. However, I solved my problem by completely opting ArcGIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be simple to convert the file as the formats are very similar.
An ArcGIS .clr file is a space delimited text file where each line takes the form:

```
INDEX R G B
```

Example:

```
1 255 255 0
2 64 0 128
3 255 32 32
4 0 255 0
5 0 0 255
```

A QGIS colour map file is similar but takes the form:

```
INDEX R G B ALPHA INDEX
```

Example:

```
0 247 251 255 255 0
1 247 251 255 255 1
2 246 251 255 255 2
4 245 250 255 255 4
```

You could make the ArcGIS .clr compatible with QGIS by adding an alpha value of 255 and the input index for each entry.

References:

Arcgis:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/creating-a-color-map-clr-file.htm

Qgis: Exporting a colour map file and comparing