# Converting ArcGIS raster colormap file (*.clr) to QGIS style file (*.qml)

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcmap, colormap, qml

I have an ArcGIS colormap (*.clr) and I want to open it in QGIS to apply a predefined style.

The *.clr file is really simple, only has four columns representing `[value] [red] [green] [blue]`, as this example:

```
19 161 161 161
21 152 181 129
22 114 168 144
23 124 142 173
```

Is there a way to read these columns and convert them in a QGIS style file (*.qml)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nice answer from [@whyzar](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/35779/whyzar)! You could load *.clr* files into QGIS **and then save it** as a *.qml* file. As described in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/235026/loading-geotiff-with-specified-color-band-from-arcgis-to-qgis), the standard text format is:

```
Value R G B Alpha Label
```

So in your case, you could create a text file with:

```
19,161,161,161,255,19
21,152,181,129,255,21
22,114,168,144,255,22
23,124,142,173,255,23
```

And load it from the menu:

[image: Result]

You can then edit and save the style as a *.qml*.

---

From [@Stefan's](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/15459/stefan) comment, I've included some quick code which reformats the input text file in a way that QGIS can read it (hopefully!):

```
main_path = 'path/to/directory/'
with open(main_path + 'infile.txt') as infile, open(main_path + 'outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        value = line.split(' ')[0]
        line = line.replace(' ', ',').rstrip('\n') + ',255,' + value + '\n'
        outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: Thanks for highlighting out the differences between these two color map files. A little bit of Python code and there could be a new QGIS Plugin.

Comment: @Stefan - Most welcome! And I look forward to your plugin ;)

Comment: @Stefan - Thought I'd have a go and write up some code to hopefully do the above automatically =)

Comment: @Joseph perfect, I've been testing it and works. Thanks!

Comment: @aldo_tapia - Most welcome! Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 5):

I haven't yet to find a clean cut way to do this. I have come across different resources that can offer option to work with in attempting to achieve what you are interested in.

[Converting/using ArcGIS *.style file for/in QGIS (QML or SLD)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71719/converting-using-arcgis-style-file-for-in-qgis-qml-or-sld)

> The style file might be for ARCGIS users. It is not in a human readable format.
>
> QGIS uses XML-files to store styling properties, so you have no luck with just renaming the extension.
>
> I am not aware of any ESRI-to-QGIS style converter.

and also an alternative

> Another option might be to save the style as a .lyr file. Then use http://wald.intevation.org/projects/arcmap2sld/ to convert the .lyr file to an SLD and then use that SLD within QGIS
>
> In QGIS, right click on the layer > properties > load style then use the drop down box to select SLD