# Load and convert .txt file to .qml for raster color map

Tags: qgis, qml

I have a "QGIS Generated Color Map Export File" in .txt format.  I'm trying to load it using QGIS 2.18 but the only file extension QGIS will accept is .qml file format.  [This question relates what I'm trying to do but provides no explanation as to how to load a non-qml file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/257997/converting-arcgis-raster-colormap-file-clr-to-qgis-style-file-qml).

The file I'm trying to utilize is located here: http://www.warrenpinnacle.com/prof/SLAMM/GCPLCC/slamm_colors_qgis.txt

Comment: Please, update your question with the txt file you want to use. In my QGIS when I follow the Q&A in your own question I can open only .txt files and no .qml files. I sugest to review the instructions and check what the folder icon offer you to open

Comment: The responses to the other question begin with an Esri clr file.  I'm trying to begin with a .txt file.

Comment: I am importing .txt color templet but it is not uploading. What might be the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are trying to open the .txt file from the Style buttom. You must open the file from another place. Review this picture where I opened your file without a problem. I made a red circle in the folder icon you need to use.

[image]