# Loading RGB legend for vector layer from text file using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology, style

I have a shapefile with one field containing a code for geological unit. I don't have ArcGIS Desktop l and therefore cannot access the layer file. However, from the source, I obtained a text file containing a line for each discrete code, its RGB definition, an entry for what I think is opacity, and a Text value for the legend.

What I want to do is load this text file and associate the contents with the appropriate field to define a style, which can then be saved in standard QGIS format.

I have seen two questions and answers about loading style from a text file for raster layers:

- [Load and convert .txt file to .qml for raster color map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260906/load-and-convert-txt-file-to-qml-for-raster-color-map)
- https://pvanb.wordpress.com/2014/02/05/creating-a-qgis-color-map-from-text-file/

However, I cannot see any questions about how to do this with vector layers.

Do I have to manually edit my file into an XML-type style file or is there a quick option?

My file has this format at present (but can be readily changed):

## QGIS Generated Color Map Export File

INTERPOLATION:EXACT
0,255,255,255,255,None

773,84,201,84,1,UISD-MFIR

42,176,219,255,1,KKF-WACKE

etc etc (note there are no spaces between lines but I have put them in for clarity. Also the first 2 lines were copied from one of the questions and inserted into my file, so they may not be relevant)

I am using v3.8.3.

Comment: have you tried loading the text file as a table, joining it to the vector layer, and using the RGBA values with the expression builder's color functions to set the layer colors?

Comment: Thanks @csk that is a useful solution for displaying the data with correct colors. However, I was interested to then save the legend as a style, and I'm not sure how to do this from the approach you suggest.